# Terraform Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

New to terraform and i got stuck on somehting and i cannot advance. Im having problems with a policy creation it seems and what i could find on internet is rather deprecated... acan anyone help?

> error i get:
> Error: putting S3 Bucket (web-net-app-andreiweb-aasdasfasfasdasg234dsf21312b) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 3082W83VXY47PFBR, HostID: hLSrf/QmpECefnmArGbhMy2bv4+lVCdqsdPj5SkRt2cgJ611hUZfJ2/6YuWF5pj1l4ACI3HH8pM=, api error MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
> │
> │   with aws_s3_bucket_policy.s3bucket_allow_all,
> │   on s3.tf line 13, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3bucket_allow_all":
> │   13: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3bucket_allow_all" {

This is my s3.tf file

```
# aws_s3_bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "myFirstBucket" {
  bucket        = local.s3_bucket_name
  force_destroy = true #sterge bucket-ul chiar daca nu este gol
  tags          = local.common_tags

}

# aws_s3_bucket policy

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3bucket_allow_all" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : "*",
        "Action" : "*",
        "Resource" : "*"
      }
    ]
  })
}


# aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "myFirstBucket-public-access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "s3_bucket_ownership" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.id
  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"
  }
}

# S3 Bucket ACL
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "bucket-acl" {
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls.s3_bucket_ownership]

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.id
  acl    = "private"
}

# aws_s3_object

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.id
  key    = "/website/Globo_logo_Vert.png"
  source = "./website/Globo_logo_Vert.png"

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "site" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.id
  key    = "/website/index.html"
  source = "./website/index.html"
}
```

this is my lb.tf file

```
# aws_elb_service_account

# aws_lb
resource "aws_lb" "nginx" {
  name                       = "test-lb-web-net-2024"
  internal                   = false
  load_balancer_type         = "application"
  security_groups            = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
  subnets                    = [aws_subnet.public_subnet0.id, aws_subnet.public_subnet1.id]
  depends_on                 = [aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket]
  enable_deletion_protection = false
  tags                       = local.common_tags
  /*  access_logs {
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.bucket
    prefix  = "alb-logs"
    enabled = true
  } */
}

# aws_lb_target_group

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nginx" {
  name     = "nginxTargetGroup"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.app.id

  tags = local.common_tags
}

# aws_lb_listener

resource "aws_lb_listener" "nginx" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.nginx.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn
  }
  tags = local.common_tags
}

#aws_lb_target_group_attachment

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nginx1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.nginx1.id
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nginx2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.nginx2.id
  port             = 80
}
```

Comment: I think you want something like `"Resource" : [ aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.arn,  "${aws_s3_bucket.myFirstBucket.arn}/*"]`.

Comment: Hey i did that but i get a new error posted  to the answer i got :(

Comment: Well, the answers are correct, the issue you are seeing is a different thing.